# Few initial character are missing while AES decryption using openssl

Tags: openssl, aes

I have done the encryption for the file through code using IVStatic = true and keysize = 256.

Now I am trying to decrypt the file using openssl commands.

1. I extracted IV from the IV from the file.
2. then I removed the IV from the file.
3. get SHA256 encryption of the encrypted key.
4. used openssl -d command to decrypt with all the parameters like encryption key(SHA 256), IV etc.
5. the file decrypt successfully. But initial characters are missing.

Please help

Comment: If the first block is wrong the IV is wrong. As Henno states the IV may not be the first block. Or there many be additional tings prepended to the encryption. It would help if an example of encrypted text, 40 characters were provided with the key and encrypted output in hex.

Comment: SHA256 is not encryption...

Answer (score 0):

As a thought: IVStatic suggests that a fixed IV is being used. So don't extract the IV (or what you think of as the IV) but use IV= zeroblock instead and see what the start of the file becomes. I assume the key is OK, as the padding must have checked out for the key you used....

The text will be 16 bytes longer at the beginning, but maybe it will turn out (comparing the expected start with the IV=0 decryption, that another IV has been used, just xor the expected start block with the decrypted one.